# SQL Database Indexing

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

There is a live database which is updated frequently. Now is it now possible to add indexing to it. If yes what is the procedure

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit the question to represent your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is to run multiple `CREATE INDEX` statements, I presume.